# Object not being returned in MVC Razor Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple user manager console to change roles on users. The two main methods are:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Use Entity Framework and get all users and their roles
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(UserRoleManagerContainer mgr)
{
    //recieve updated object and reassign roles
}
```

In my C# page, I have the following code, which does show all the users and their roles when the page loads:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UsersInRoles.Count; i++)
        {
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Model.UsersInRoles[i].User.UserName
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.UsersInRoles[i].Roles.Count; j++)
                    {
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.UsersInRoles[i].Roles[j].Name)
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="update roles" />
}
```

Unfortunately, when the `HttpPost` triggers I'm getting an empty object back.

Here is the object I am trying to pass back:

```
public class UserRoleManagerContainer
{
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public List<UserInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }

    public UserRoleManagerContainer()
    {
        Roles = new List<string>();
        UsersInRoles = new List<UserInRoles>();
    }
}
public class UserInRoles
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public List<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked much with async, but I think you have to specify to the view that you are expecting an async back, that way it will not load until after the async finishes.

Comment: async methods just run synchronously if there is no await call. There is an await in the commented code.

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine. If its not, its because of code you have not shown.